# How to include anonymous functions into RequireJS dependencies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, anonymous-function

I am starting to use RequireJS now and I was already able to add my project dependencies but I still cannot add a jQuery anonymous function yet.

For example, with my normal_file.js I do something like:

**normal_file.js**:

```
define(['dependency1'], function(Dependency) {
    var Test1 = ...;
    return Test1;
});
```

Bu from a file that has no module, like the example below, I don't know how to encapsulate it:

**lib_file.js**:

```
(function ($) {
    // Do stuff...
})(window.jQuery);
```

the lib_file was not made by me and I'm not sure on how it really works, but I would gess it is an anonymous auto-executed function, is that so?.

Anyway, my goal is to use both files in my main code, like below:

**main.js**:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl:'/static/editorial/js/',
    paths: {
        jquery:  'third_party/jquery-1.10.2',
        react:   'third_party/react-with-addons'
    }
});


var dependencies = [
    'third_party/react-with-addons',
    'third_party/jquery-1.10.2',
    'build/utils/normal_file,
    'third_party/lib_file
];

require(dependencies, function(React, $, Test1, ??) {
    // do my stuff
});
```

How should I encapsulate that anonymous function in order to add it as a dependency to my main file?

Answer (score 1):

From the RequireJS docs:

> Ideally the scripts you load will be modules that are defined by
>   calling define(). However, you may need to use some traditional/legacy
>   "browser globals" scripts that do not express their dependencies via
>   define(). For those, you can use the shim config. To properly express
>   their dependencies.

Read this: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim
It has a really good explanation of what you have to do, and gives a nice example.

Basically, you just need to set up a shim config for `lib_file.js` so Require knows to load the right dependencies before giving you access to that script.